# Why this javascript executes in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, firefox

I need to set the "cmd" hidden text to the values below. Chrome executes this scripts, but Firefox (at least 3.6) doesn't.

I've checked the java in firefox, also the "execute javascript" option. I've been running jquery stuff in firefox quite well. What should I do?

```
function envia() {

    frm = document.forms['detalha'];
    tx = frm.elements("cmd");

    tx.value = '0';
    alert('document pressed' + document.pressed);
    if (document.pressed == '2') {
        tx.value = '2';
    } else if (document.pressed == '3') {
        tx.value = '3';
    } else if (document.pressed == '4') {
        tx.value = '4';
    }
    return true;
}
<form name="detalha" action="/publicopj/Altera" onsubmit="envia()">

<input type="submit" value="Save" name="acao" onclick="document.pressed=3"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where/how is the envia() function triggered?

Comment: @MarcB, I'm sorry, I forgot. I've updated the code above, with "onsubmit" statement. Looking in Firefox Developer console, I saw an error "frm.element" is not a function. Probably Firefox haven't this method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.forms[...].elements` is an array, not a function. You've got `()` on your .elements bit, trying to call it as a function.

```
tx = frm.elements["cmd"];  // note the square brackets
```

Comment: More technically accurate, it is not an array, it's supposed to be a NodeList, though most browsers actually return a HTMLCollection.  In Trident and possibly some other browsers, you can call a HTMLCollection or NodeList like a function, and in this case it maps to `elements.item(arg)`.  Gecko, as discovered, doesn't support this.